# How to retrieve records for last n minutes in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to retrieve the last n records from a table based on the value of n set in another table.

```
$db->query("SELECT sum(mfz_temp) FROM main_freezer WHERE ts >=  DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL n MINUTE)")->fetchColumn()

ts = date/time stamp: 2016-05-19 09:30:46

mfz_temp = int(3): -21

n minutes = int(2): 10 [comes from: mfz_temp_alarm_delay FROM main_freezer_config]
```

this formula will give the freezers average temperature over the last `n` minutes.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: awesome. looks good.

Comment: How do I include the number from n in the SQL statement?